# Accessing a specific string using rangeOfString in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm using NSURLConnection to pull data from a webpage. I'm looking to find a specific line of text to display in a basic app. I've converted my NSData to an NSString. The program successfully locates the string I'm looking for:

```
@"Most recent instantaneous value:
```

However, I need to actually pull and store the string that follows "instantaneous value: *myString* "

I'm noob, so I'm stuck. Here's my code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://waterdata.usgs.gov/ga/nwis/uv?cb_72036=on&cb_00062=on&format=gif_default&period=1&site_no=02334400"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if (connection) {
    // Connect
    label.text = @"Connecting...";
    myData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
} else {
    // Error
}
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data 
{
[myData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading: (NSURLConnection *)connection {
response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
label.text = response;

NSString *string1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
if ([string1 rangeOfString:@"Most recent instantaneous value: "].location == NSNotFound){
    NSLog(@"Not found");
} else
{
    NSLog(@"Found");
}
connection = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends no the format of what follows.  You can easily use a regular expression to extract this value if it has a delimiter.  For example, let's say it looks like this:

...Most recent instantaneous value: 74219MoredataBlahBLahBlah

This would be extracted using the regular expression "Most recent instantaneous value: ([0-9]+)"

However, if it is something like this

...Most recent instantaneous value: MyValueMoredataBlahBLahBlah

Then you are pretty much out of luck unless it is the same size each time

If it is like this

......Most recent instantaneous value: MyValue MoredataBlahBLahBlah

Then you can get it like this "...Most recent instantaneous value: ([A-Z,a-z]+ )" (note the space at the end inside the parenthesis).

Could you perhaps tell a bit more about the format of your value?

**EDIT:**

Since you know the length of your string, just do as shown above and when you get here:

```
NSString *restOfString = [string1 substringFromIndex:theRange.location+theRange.length];
```

Continue with this:  `NSString *cutString = [restOfString substringToIndex:8];`

Comment: The value is a 8 character number. Something like 1,034.45

Comment: How exactly would I use: "Most recent instantaneous value: ([0-9]+)"

Comment: An NSRegularExpression object :) http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: So in your case, you would want a regex like this:  "Most recent instantaneous value: ([0-9,.]{8})" and you would get the match at index ONE, not ZERO.  Index zero will contain the whole regex match, and index one will contain what is inside the parenthesis.  You can test your regular expressions at http://www.regextester.com

Comment: Actually, on second thought, see my edited answer because there is an easier way if you know the length of the string.

Answer (score 2):

You already have half the solution:

```
NSRange range = [string1 rangeOfString:@"Most recent instantaneous value: "];
if (range.location == NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"Not found");
} else {
     NSLog(@"Found");
     // Method 1
     NSString *string2 = [string1 stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
     NSLog(@"%@", string2);

     // Method 2
     NSString *string3 = [string1 substringFromIndex:range.location+range.length];
     NSLog(@"%@", string3);
}
```

Both methods produce the result you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A good general tip for this sort of problem is to look at the documented methods in the [NSString Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html). For example, the section under "Dividing Strings" has a few options for you, including

```
– substringFromIndex:
```

Your code might go something like this

```
NSString *string1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSRange theRange = [string1 rangeOfString:@"Most recent instantaneous value: "];
if (theRange.location == NSNotFound){
    NSLog(@"Not found");
} else
{
    NSString *restOfString = [string1 substringFromIndex:theRange.location+theRange.length];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ComponentSeparatedBy ":" should work.